# Excel function to search column to find any matches from list of text

Tags: excel, function, search, text, match

**Column to be searched**   **Column to match against**   **results**
text1...                        text1
Text2  ..                      test
Text3
Text4
text1

I need a formula to search the column1 (Column to be searched) looking to see if any texts in column2 (Column to match against) is in column1. And then if there is a match display True/1 and False/0 if not.

E.g. Column1 Cell2 has "text1" which is being searched for in **ALL** columns (references from column2) so column3 in cell2 should show True (or 1).

Functions I have tried:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(DQ2:$DQ$8, F1)))
=MATCH($DQ$2:$DQ$8, F2,-1)
=VLOOKUP(1, F2:$DQ$2:$DQ$8, 1)
=IF(COUNTIF(F2, "data"),"TRUE","FALSE")
=(COUNTIF($DQ$2:$DQ$8, F1)>0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for cell C4:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B4,A:A,0)),0,1)
```

The MATCH function will try to find the value of B4 within Column A and if it doesn't find a perfect match, it will return an error (and the ISERROR will return 0 for errors)

The IF function creates the desired 1 or 0 value based on the outcome.